# Why do I get "end of file found before the left brace '{' in hashtable.h(8)"?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

It gives that error when i try to compile and I don't know why because both set of braces are matched.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <list>
   #include <string>
   #include <utility>
   #include <fstream>

  namespace cop4530 {

  template <typename T>
  class HashTable {
  public:
        HashTable(size_t size = 101);
        ~HashTable();
        bool contains(const T &);
        bool insert(const T &);
        bool insert(T && );
        bool remove(const T& );
        void clear();
        bool load(const char *);
        void dump();
        bool write_to_file(const char *);

        // used when improper size is given (for example
        // size is 0 or negative)
        static const unsigned int default_capacity = 11;
        static const unsigned int max_prime = 1301081;

    private:
        std::vector<std::list<T>> listTab;
        void makeEmpty();
        void rehash();
        size_t myhash(const T &);
        unsigned long prime_below(unsigned long);
        void setPrimes(std::vector<unsigned long> &);
        int currentSize;
   }; // end of HashTable

   #include "hashtable.hpp"

   };   // end of namespace 4530
```

Or is the problem possibly in the .hpp or even the main.cpp?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure this changes something, but dit you try putting the #include "hashtable.hpp" outside your namespace?

Comment: Is the file we're seeing "hashtable.h"? If so, why are you including it from itself? If not, why aren't we seeing it? it's where the error is.

Comment: I think it's in hashtable.hpp, but you would have already checked that, and I don't know why the error would be reported in one header but not another.

Comment: Please confirm your compiler? Is it C++11-compliant?

Comment: what is `#include "hashtable.hpp"` doing at the bottom of your code?

Comment: It's probably something in hashtable.hpp

Comment: The error may be ultimately caused by the code preceding `#include "hashtable.h"` in another file.

Comment: @NathanOliver That file contains the implementation of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Here :

```
vector<std::list<T>>
```

The `>>` Is a token that most compiler read as an operator, like the one in this line:

```
std::cin >> toto;
```

It makes your compiler become crazy from this line and print strange errors after.

Insert a space to define it as a double template bracket token :

```
vector<std::list<T> >
```

Comment: The question is marked as C++11, so that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Since C++11 >> is allowed on templates

Comment: I remember to have a problem like that, and it was in C++11 If I remember well... I would like the @user3513265 confirmation...

Answer (score 0):

There is no semicolon after the closing bracket for namespaces.

Comment: It's not required but allowed, though.

Comment: Oh, but there is! :) maybe Sid is trying to say that there shouldn't be (though it shouldn't matter).

Comment: Good to know having semicolon there does not matter! :) (I didn't know)